# mktime function of LIBC returns different values for the same input

Tags: c++, c, timezone, glibc, mktime

We know that timezone UTC+8 has some clock changes. For example, on January 1st 1928, 00:00:00 the clock was turned backward 0:05:52 hours to 31 December 1927, 23:54:08.
Besides, in the year 1940-1941 and 1986-1991 the daylight saving time was used. When I'm testing the function `mktime` under linux with these dates, I have different return values. The code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct tm timeinfo;
    memset(&timeinfo, 0, sizeof(timeinfo));

    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d%d%d%d%d%d",
            &timeinfo.tm_year, &timeinfo.tm_mon, &timeinfo.tm_mday,
            &timeinfo.tm_hour, &timeinfo.tm_min, &timeinfo.tm_sec) != EOF)
    {
        timeinfo.tm_year -= 1900;
        timeinfo.tm_mon -= 1;
        fprintf(stdout, "%lld\n", mktime(&timeinfo));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The test input and output for example is like that, the same input "1940 6 2 23 59 59" and "1940 6 3 1 0 0" will have different return value depending on the calling sequence:

```
1940 6 2 23 59 59
-933494401    
1940 6 3 1 0 0
-933490800
1940 6 3 1 0 0
-933494400
1940 6 2 23 59 59
-933498001
1940 6 2 23 59 59
-933494401
```

The same input 1940 6 3 1 0 0

Why is that? Why the return value of `mktime` is different depending on the calling sequence?

I've read some version of source code of `mktime` but didn't find any part of the code that might cause this problem.

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Thanks a lot.

Newly added cases:

```
1927 12 31 23 54 8
-1325491552
1927 12 31 23 54 7
-1325491905
1927 12 31 23 54 8
-1325491904
1928 1 1 0 0 0
-1325491200
1927 12 31 23 54 8
-1325491552
```

Comment: Suggest: Better to use `while(fscanf(stdin, "%d%d%d%d%d%d", ...) == 6)`

Comment: Before calling `mktime(&timeinfo)`, use `timeinfo.tm_isdst = -1` (DST not available) to avoid inheriting the previous value.  Only `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` can be left uninitialized.

Comment: try `"%lld\n"` --> `"%ld\n"` and check Is `time_t` type `long long int`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is correct, consider `fprintf(stdout, "%lld\n", (long long) mktime(&timeinfo));` to remove potential `printf()` problems.

Comment: "Why the return value of mktime are different and depending on the calling sequence? "Because only 6 of the needed 7 fields are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with `timeinfo.tm_isdst` set to 0, which asks `mktime` to consider the time as non-DST.

`mktime` will then normalize the `struct tm` passed in so that the fields are in their proper ranges; part of that process will adjust the DST flag based on whether DST was actually in effect at the specified time. (See [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).) If DST is in effect, it will set that flag to a positive value and adjust the other fields of the `struct tm` accordingly.

Later iterations of your loop will overwrite the six fields passed to your `fscanf`, but not the DST field. Thus, if an earlier iteration of the loop resulted in that flag being set, a later iteration will   still have the flag being set. As a result, you are not actually passing the same time to `mktime`, and it returns different results.

From what you are printing, the scenario seems to be:

```
1940 6 2 23 59 59  // tm_isdst == 0, asks mktime to consider this non-DST, and DST not in effect at this time
-933494401         // tm_isdst still 0
1940 6 3 1 0 0     // tm_isdst == 0, asks mktime to consider this non-DST, but at this time DST was in effect
-933490800         // tm_isdst now positive
1940 6 3 1 0 0     // tm_isdst > 0, asks mktime to consider this DST, and DST was actually in effect
-933494400         // tm_isdst still positive
1940 6 2 23 59 59  // tm_isdst > 0, asks mktime to consider this DST, but actually DST wasn't in effect
-933498001         // tm_isdst becomes 0
1940 6 2 23 59 59  // tm_isdst == 0, asks mktime to consider this non-DST
-933494401         // tm_isdst still 0
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ccb818c7c2776eb).

Comment: this could explain the first and the second being different, but doesn't explain the second and the third invocation. the DST field is already set there to whatever mktime sets it. Also I'm not sure I'm believing you about mktime adjusting it's input. I'd be a horribly bad design.

Comment: @EvanDark Feel free to consult the documentation yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: @T.C. It is really helpful. Thanks a lot. I have some cases that cannot be explained. These cases is added in the text

Comment: @ZiyuChen I can't repro this, but first print out all the fields of your `struct tm` before and after the `mktime` call to see if any changed.

Comment: @T.C. The tm_isdst field, tm_year,..,tm_sec field before and after the mktime call is not changed when I try these cases. The clock change in Shanghai in 1927 is not about daylight saving time. [This page](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/china/shanghai?year=1927) may be useful.

Comment: @ZiyuChen What happens if you add a `memset(&timeinfo, 0, sizeof(timeinfo));` right after your `fprintf` call?

Comment: @T.C. As to the added cases, the result is the same. The added cases is not about the dst. The behavior is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably isn't with `mktime` but with `sscanf`. I can't test it since for me your example works (well I'm not sure it's the correct time, but it's consistent) but it's very likely that `scanf` is reading less numbers than it should, and this way the input from the prevoius line gets mixed in with the current one.

`fscanf` is known to have a problem with line endings, so check the return value (it should be `6`) value try reading line by line with `fgets` into a buffer, and then use `sscanf`.